¿Cómo depurar código Javascript usando la extensión: Microsoft Edge Tools para Visual Studio Code?
Este es mi archivo de configuracion para el debug de VS Code:
{
  "configurations": [
    
  {
    "name": "Attach to Edge",
    "port": 9222,
    "request": "attach",
    "type": "msedge",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
  },
    {
      "name": "Launch Edge",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "msedge",
      "url": "http://localhost:8848/Login_PHP/",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "name": "Login PHP - Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:8848/Login_PHP/"
    },
    {
      "type": "pwa-msedge",
      "name": "Launch Microsoft Edge",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
      ],
      "url": "c:\\Users\\MAGNAN1MUS\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-edgedevtools.vscode-edge-devtools-2.1.5\\out\\startpage\\index.html", // Provide your project's url to finish configuring
      "presentation": {
        "hidden": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "pwa-msedge",
      "name": "Launch Microsoft Edge in headless mode",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--headless",
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
      ],
      "url": "c:\\Users\\MAGNAN1MUS\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-edgedevtools.vscode-edge-devtools-2.1.5\\out\\startpage\\index.html", // Provide your project's url to finish configuring
      "presentation": {
        "hidden": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "vscode-edge-devtools.debug",
      "name": "Open Edge DevTools",
      "request": "attach",
      "url": "http://localhost:8848/Login_PHP/", // Provide your project's url to finish configuring
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",

      "presentation": {
        "hidden": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Edge Headless and attach DevTools",
      "configurations": [
        "Launch Microsoft Edge in headless mode",
        "Open Edge DevTools"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch Edge and attach DevTools",
      "configurations": [
        "Launch Microsoft Edge",
        "Open Edge DevTools"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

He intentado de todo con varios modos, pero solo consigo que me funcione la depuración lanzándola desde un navegador externo y no con la extensión de Microsoft Edge Tools, aclaro que estoy tratando de depurar desde esta URL: http://localhost:8848/Login_PHP/, la cual copie y pegué en la barra del navegador de Edge Tools. Qué debo hacer para que me funcione? Hay alguna configuración que deba realizar? O no hay forma de conseguirlo? Gracias de antemano por cualquier pista o ayuda

Una disculpa, ya me funciona el debug con la configuración: Attach to Edge, por algún motivo antes no funcionaba
